# How do I import a module from a Python script that's two directories above?

Tags: python, importerror

Let's say that I have a project with the directory structure as follows:

```
project
      \__ cfgs
             \__ __init__.py
             \__ config.py
      \__ src
            \__ __init__.py
            \__ model1
                     \__ __init__.py
                     \__ test.py
            \__ model2
                     \__ test2.py
```

I want to run the Python script `test.py`. However, I need to import a module named `Config` from the file `project/cfgs/config.py`. How would I correctly import it?

Within `test.py` I've tried the following:

```
# Returns a `No module named 'cfgs'` error.
from cfgs import Config

# Returns `Attempted relative import with no known parent package` error.
from ..cfgs import Config
```

Comment: You need to set your project up as a package first, see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28154841/).  Once your project is set up as a proper package and put the files into the correct directories the problems with import issues will go away